# Overhead Bend Effect With Design

Tags: adobe-photoshop, design-principles, perspective

Graphic Artist Gurus Unite!

I have experience in Photoshop (CS4) but mostly with simple image editing for website design (cropping, resizing, working with packaged mockups, etc).

When it comes to dimensions, perspective angles, etc. I clearly get lost.

MY QUESTION:

How to I create the visual appearance of a rectangular shape that is flat on top and about 3/4 the way down the "piece" bends downward?

Image attached shows design in photoshop (left side -overhead view of a metal clip) and the actual metal clip (right) showing the downward bend I want to create in the image design on left.[image: SEE THIS IMAGE]

Thank you

Comment: A shadow created with gradients

Answer (score 1):

I first created the hexagon shape in Illustrator. I then brought the shape to Photoshop.

[image: Shape]

I then duplicated the layer CTRL/CMD + J.

I am going to have 2 layers. I picked a point about a 1/3 of the way down and used a vector mask to hide the parts. So the top layer had the bottom 1/3rd hidden and the bottom layer had the top 2/3 hidden.

[image: View of my layers]

**The bottom layer**, I will bend slightly inwards at the bottom using the Distort tool (CTRL/CMD + T). I then squish the layer vertically.

[image: bottom layer bend]

**The Top layer**, I will bend slightly inwards at the top using the distort tool (CTRL/CMD + T). I do not scale the image in any direction.

[image: Top layer bend]

I did have to use the warp tool on the top layer to match the 2 layers together since the distortion misaligned the points.

[image: Align the top layer to the bottom layer]

I then grouped the images together by rasterizing them. I added a gradient shadow to the bottom part of the object.

Result

[image: End result of bend]

Other things that might help with the illusion, I would maybe add a gaussian blur to part of the shadow.

**NOTE**: It is probably better to just delete the parts instead of using a layer mask (Just remember to make duplicates in case you mess up). It will then be easier to distort the shapes.